# Can I update 1 object only with Linq to SQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Its a simple question, but I'm not aware of the answer and I couldn't get it to work.

Can I update only one entity on the entire DataContext? Or should I follow plain ADO.NET for this operation only?

**Edit:**

```
public MyObject GetMyObjectById(int selectedId)
    {
        DataContext db = _dbManager.GetContext();

        return db.MyObject.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == selectedId);
    }
```

I am getting an object with the above query...
I am querying then for an integer...on another table/object

```
 public int GetMyInteger()
    {
        DataContext db = _dbManager.GetContext();

        return db.MyAnotherObject.FirstOrDefault().MyInteger;
    }
```

Everything is fine for all my operations...but now i just want to update only the integer i got from the database...

```
 public void SetMyInteger(int updInteger)
    {
        DataContext db = new DataContext(ConnectionString);

        MyAnotherObject theEntity = db.MyAnotherObject.FirstOrDefault();
        atheEntity.MyInteger = updInteger;
        db.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
    }
```

The above method deleted MyObject i got from the first query!!! Of course if i use the static context DataContext tries to update MyObject and MyAnotherObject which seems the correct behaviour.

**Edit:**

I have changed the method getting the integer with a new datacontext as well and seems to working correctly, i have a strange thought on why called the delete method, because it was the method that was called, but again .. is working now...

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible. What have you tried? It should be as simple as this:

```
using (var dc = new YourDataContext())
{
    Person p = dc.Persons.Take(1).Single();
    p.FirstName = "Ahmad";
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Yes tried but in one way where i use same datacontext for all my operations and while i have loaded some other objects, i get error from the other objects in the context, then tried doing this with a new DataContext and it deleted me the other object from the DataBase!!! you realize the bad of this :) but updated what i wanted too...so i think i need the way of updating only the entity i need ....somehow

Comment: @gtas: This answer demonstrates quite clearly the solution: you need to create a new datacontext when you start a new operation / transaction.

Comment: @gtas if you're referencing multiple objects from the same DataContext and make changes to them, then all changes will be sent once you use `SubmitChanges()`. The simplest option is to use a single DataContext for the update. Or you can try performing the update you need, call `SubmitChanges()`, then continue with your work on the other items.

Comment: Strange is i tried with a new datacontext and Deleted me the other object i had loaded with another datacontext...xmmmmm

Comment: @gtas if these suggestions don't work then please update your question with an example of your code so we can have a better idea of the problem.

Comment: @gtas - are you attempting this in a web based scenario?  It kind of sounds like multiple objects are being inserted or updated via the same data context.  If you are running in to problems in a web scenario, you may want to try and create just one data context per request.

Comment: i am choosing this as a correct answer because here is the conversation Mark was right as well and helped of course as everyone thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can:

```
Foo foo = dc.Foos.Where(foo => foo.Id == 345).Single();
foo.Name = "foo";
dc.SubmitChanges();
```